# What is canonical URL?

Tags: html, seo

What is canonical URL?
what is the use of canonical URL?
How to add canonical URL in my website?

Right now my website is loading very slow,some one suggested me to add canonical URL,but i don't have much idea on canonical URL.

please suggest me!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A canonical page is the preferred version of a set of pages with highly similar content.

The following link may clear your doubt!

[rel="canonical"](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139394?hl=en)